# check if a value belongs to a certain object

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, equality

I have a map with two different kinds of objects: deposit account and checking account. I want to write a money transfer methode to transfer money between two checking accounts only. Is there a way to check if both account numbers belong to the same checking account object?

```
bool Bank::moneyTransfer(long fromAccount,long toAccount, double amount)
{
    map<long, account*>::iterator iterFrom;
    map<long, account*>::iterator iterTo;

    iterFrom = m_accountList.find(fromAccount);
    if (iterFrom == m_accountList.end()) {
        return false;
    }
    iterTo = m_account.find(toAccount);
    if (iterFrom == m_accountList.end()) {
        return false;
    }

    Konto *fromAccount = iterFrom->second;
    Konto *toAccount = iterTo->second;

    if (!fromAccount->drawMoney(amount)) {
        return false;
    }
    toAccount->payIn(amount);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: In your logic, would the two account numbers not simply be the same (i.e. `fromAccount == toAccount`)?

Comment: You could possibly use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to make sure that the account if of a specific type, ***if*** you have polymorphic classes.

Comment: To be able to answer that question we need to know how `Konto` and `account` are defined, and as @JoachimPileborg wrote: if there is some kind of polymophism.

Answer (score 0):

### Q. Is there a way to check if both account numbers belong to the same checking account object?

### A. Yes

As [Shaktal says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097113/check-if-a-value-belongs-to-a-certain-object#comment63628688_38097113) you're passing in the account numbers just compare them.

There are a couple things that need to be cleaned up in your code:

1. The fact that you're asking this question indicated that the you think that you could have the same Key in a `map` with 2 Values. This is not the case, this code will result in the Key 13 mapping to *only* a `DepositAccount`:

```
m_accountList[13] = CheckingAccount();
m_accountList[13] = DepositAccount();
```

2. Please use `auto` to declare your variables, especially instead of `map<long, account*>::iterator` aside from being easier to read, you wont have to come back and edit your logic when you change `m_accountList`'s type, for more information on `auto` I believe the definitive article is: https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

After making these corrections, your code should look something like:

```
bool Bank::moneyTransfer(long fromAccount, long toAccount, double amount)
{
    if(fromAccount != toAccount) {
         auto iterFrom = m_accountList.find(fromAccount);

        if (iterFrom != m_accountList.end()) {
            auto iterTo = m_account.find(toAccount);

            if (iterFrom != m_accountList.end() && iterFrom->second->drawMoney(amount)) {
                iterTo->second->payIn(amount);

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```